# Rspec + Capybara : How to click on alert box

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have gone through the post of capybara + click on alert box but nothing seems to be work. Following is my scenario:

**Scenario**: When I click update button An alert box appears which contains "OK" and "Cancel" button. Click on "Ok" then new form appears.

1. I am writing request specs i.e. using rspec and capybara. Main problem is to click on the alert box: Following is my code:

   ```
    context "update" do
      before(:all) do
        Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
      end
      after(:all) do
        Capybara.use_default_driver
      end

      it "update user to trainer" do
        click_button('Search')
        sleep 3 
        page.evaluate_script('data-confirm = function() { return true; }')
        page.click('OK')      
        click_button('Upgrade')
      end
    end
   ```

   But executing script gives me following error:

   > Failure/Error: page.evaluate_script('data-confirm = function() { return true; }') Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedJavascriptError: invalid assignment left-hand side # ./spec/requests/user_upgrades_spec.rb:30
2. For the second example i.e.

   > page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept

   My code :

   ```
    context "update" do
      before(:all) do
        Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
      end
      after(:all) do
        Capybara.use_default_driver
      end
      it "update user to trainer" do
        click_button('Search')
        sleep 3   
        click_button('Upgrade') 
        page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
      end
    end
   ```

I get error:

> Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError:

Please let me know how to proceed further

Comment: You can't name a JavaScript variable with dashes. `data-confirm = function ...` is illegal. It looks like `(foo - bar) = function() { ... }`. That's the `left-hand side # ...user_upgrades_spec.rb:30` error. Name your JavaScript variables with camelCase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384040/test-alert-dialog-text-using-capybara-webkit-1-3-1

Answer (score 38):

You can click on an alert box like this:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback.but i had already used the above code but no success.

Comment: Not working for me either; plus, I believe the question addresses this method explicitly ( see last error message listed ).  So the answer seems to suggest using what the question already states does not work for Amit in his current set up.  Considering the context of the question, I have to down vote.  Sorry >.<

Comment: Works fine for me using capybara (1.1.2).

Comment: This is NOT working with Capybara-webkit, just like for the OP

Comment: Worked for me capybara 1.1.4. Selenium driver

Comment: For capybara-webkit: expect(page.driver.alert_messages.last).to eq text

Comment: See @JillianFoley's answer below. Comes straight out of the current Capybara README and works great.

Comment: This doesn't work. Both firefox and chrome under selenium pop out extra alert boxes with a checkbox of 'prevent this dialog from opening new dialogs' ie. UnhandledAlertError

Comment: Worked for capybara-3.4.2, selenium driver

Answer (score 35):

Updated answer here, since the options above seem to have all been deprecated.

Capybara::Session#accept_alert seems to be the best way to accomplish this now, where the action that will trigger the alert should be passed in a block.
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session:accept_alert

e.g.:

```
page.accept_alert 'Alert text here' do
    click_button('Search')
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an `undefined method `accept_alert' for #<Capybara::Session>` even though per the docs, this is a method for `Capybara::Session`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could be an older version of Capybara, `accept_alert` was introduced in [Capybara 2.4.1](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/History.md#version-241). Consider running `bundle update capybara`

Answer (score 26):

```
page.accept_alert
```

worked for me using Selenium. Other drivers will probably have their own syntax.

As Jillian Foley mentioned, it seems that other answers have been deprecated.

Comment: As @b-seven mentioned other drivers, at the time of writing, the Poltergeist driver for PhantomJS doesn't yet support `accept_alert`.

Comment: Great! Worked fine for me! @B Seven

Answer (score 16):

For WebKit:

```
page.accept_confirm { click_button "Upgrade" }
```

For Selenium:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this line if you want to click on the ok button of the alert box:

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
```

Don't forget to mark your test with the javascript flag

```
it "update user to trainer", js: true do
    ...
end
```

and enable Capybara.javascript_driver with :webkit or :selenium in your spec_helper file

Comment: Works with Capybara-Webkit :)

Comment: Of all the answers, this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but this now works in poltergeist too:

```
page.accept_alert
```