# How do I confirm a javascript popup with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I've tried several examples found online, but with no luck.  I am looking to confirm the confirm message of a delete link.  The last attempt was the code below, but that resulted in an Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError error.

```
def confirm_dialog
  page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber). The accepted answer's author agrees with duplicate.

Comment: See my answer here for the newer way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26472467/2170577

Answer (score 87):

Adding an answer for those hitting this in 2016 and beyond. You can now use Capybara directly to accept a confirmation box. You do this by wrapping the code that causes the confirmation box to appear in the [accept_confirm](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Aaccept_confirm) function.

```
accept_confirm do
  click_link 'Destroy'
end
```

Comment: In addition to wrapping your action in a block like this, for me simply calling `accept_confirm` after the action which caused the confirmation dialog also successfully proceeded past it.

Answer (score 57):

First of all switch to using Selenium as the driver by putting an @javascript tag in front of your scenario.

The following code in your cucumber step will then confirm the dialogue:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
# or
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
# or
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text
```

As @NobbZ said, this question has been asked and answered before here: [How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber/5002648#comment-8214000).

More selenium documentation available here too: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#JavaScript_dialogs

Comment: undefined method `switch_to' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:0x007ffca8a79890>

Comment: I got that undefined method error and then discovered that I didn't need the switch_to call at all because selenium (I think) is automatically returning true on any confirms.  That won't help everyone, but might help some.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman You're using RackTest. the answer refers to the selenium driver. You need to set the driver before the test is run by ``Capybara.current_driver = :selenium`` or else add js: true to the example which should set the driver to ``:selenium`` by default as it is the default ``Capybara.javascript_driver``

Comment: Works with Capybara using selenium driver in Rails. Thanks

Comment: I tried to use `page.driver.browser.switch_to` but got a DEPRECATION warning but was brought to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275359/deprecation-warning-from-capybara

Answer (score 16):

for capybara-webkit:

```
page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
page.driver.browser.reject_js_confirms
```

which is still working, but the documentation says also:

```
page.driver.accept_js_confirms!
page.driver.accept_js_confirms!
```

See https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit , search "accept_js_confirms"

Comment: It worked for me with page.driver.accept_js_confirms!
(indeed from https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)

Comment: currently this line works for capybara:

page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept

Comment: Looks like your one of those should be page.driver.reject_js_confirms!

Answer (score 10):

I've had timing issues with browser dialogs in a CI environment so I'm polling for a dialog before accepting it:

```
def accept_browser_dialog
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)
  wait.until {
    begin
      page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
      true
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
      false
    end
  }
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I had to use a sleep in the webkit test since it would fail everynow and then otherwise.

Here is what I came up with after reading everyones posts:

```
if page.driver.class == Capybara::Selenium::Driver
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
elsif page.driver.class == Capybara::Webkit::Driver
  sleep 1 # prevent test from failing by waiting for popup
  page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
else
  raise "Unsupported driver"
end
```

Comment: Yep, just be really careful not to add too many of those, it makes your tests really expensive to run (i.e. they will take longer because of the sleeps)

Answer (score 3):

try to add `:js => true` to your test.

> RSpec’s metadata feature can be used to switch to a different driver.
>   Use :js => true to switch to the javascript driver, or provide a
>   :driver option to switch to one specific driver. For example:

```
it 'will use the default js driver' :js => true do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In Capybara its very simple to accept the model window. Even we can do the same in selenium but its little tough for people who are not aware about selenium.

page.accept_modal      #This will accept the modal window

page.dismiss_modal  #This will Reject/Dismiss the modal window

Comment: This returns me `NoMethodError: private method 'accept_modal' called for #<Capybara::Session>`

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you have to add selenium to your gem-file and configure it and capybara that capybara uses selenium as the driver.

I think also that [How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber) is very similar to your question, especially the accepted answer.