# How to add confirm message with link_to Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I wanted to add confirmation message on link_to function with Ruby.

```
= link_to 'Reset message', :action=>'reset' ,:confirm=>'Are you sure?'
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - How to put a confirmation popup on a f.submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771582/rails-how-to-put-a-confirmation-popup-on-a-f-submit)

Comment: This does not appear to be an exact duplicate of the nominated exemplar.  The exemplar asks how to add confirmation to a form submission; this question asks how to add confirmation to a link.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, you should verify that your layout have **jquery_ujs**.
Best practice to do it by including it in your main *application.js*:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Check that you included *application.js* in your layout:

```
= javascript_include_tag :application
```

While, in development mode, view your source html and verify **jquery_ujs.js** exists.

Run your server and verify your link tag has **data-confirm** value, for example:

```
<a href="/articles/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete">
```

If all those steps are correct, everything should work!

*Note:* check this RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

Answer (score 152):

I might be mistaken but you don't specify a controller along with the `:action` option. Have you tried the following? Assuming you have a `messages` resource configured in your route:

```
link_to 'Reset', message_path(@message), :confirm => 'Are you sure?'
```

**EDIT**: Above is deprecated. Rails 4.0 now accepts the prompt as a data attribute. See the doc [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) (Thanks @Ricky).

```
link_to 'Reset', message_path(@message), :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}
```

Comment: I think this style is deprecated. According to the rails docs, this is now a data attribute, i.e. `…, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}`

Comment: @Ricky you do realize this question and almost all the answers on this page were posted on May 21, 2013? It is Sept 2014 right now.

Comment: Yeah. Forgive me—I'm not fully immersed in stackoverflow culture! Someone asked about this, got directed here and was confused about why `:confirm` didn't seem to work. `'data-confirm'` works but it's not really the current 'rails way'. In other words: what's the best way for me to make a note of this?

Comment: @Ricky No I should've just updated my answer to begin with so I'm sorry. I must've been having a bad day or something. Answer edited with Rails 4.0 api.

Comment: [Testing JS popups can help prevent slipping through the cracks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930927/how-do-i-confirm-a-javascript-popup-with-capybara)

Comment: I'm working on an older app we have at work and it's on Rails 3.2.8. This helped me understand why my first (newer) solution wouldn't actually give me the confirmation dialog. Thanks!

Comment: Typo. We're on Rails 3.2.18.

Answer (score 13):

Can't remember how this was done in Rails 3, but in Rails 4 you can simply:

```
<%= link_to 'Reset message', { controller: 'your_controller', action: 'reset' }, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Comment: This answer helped me the most;  grouping the parameters separately with `{` and `}` before the `data - confirm` part was what I had to do.

Answer (score 13):

```
<%= link_to 'Reset Message', data: {confirm:"Are you sure?"} %>
```

remember to add the path, between 'reset message' and data

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= link_to "Delete this article", article_path(article), method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the 
                    article?"}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
```

A button link where `article_path` is the prefix and `(article)` is passing the `id` which is required by the `method: :delete` method.
The later part of the codes adds  a confirmation msg.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
= link_to 'Reset message', {:action=>'reset'}, :confirm=>'Are you sure?'
```

or to be more clear

```
= link_to('Reset message', {:action=>'reset'}, {:confirm=>'Are you sure?'})
```

Refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

You will see that there are 3 parameters, when you are giving url as options like `{:action => ..., :controller => ...}`

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

In ruby, if the last parameter in a function call is a hash, you need not wrap it in `{}` characters (in other words, you can omit that in case, if the hash is the last parameter), so the code you have provided will be interpreted as a function call with only 2 parameters, `'Reset message'` string and `{:action=>'reset', :confirm=>'Are you sure?'}` hash and the `:confirm=>'Are you sure?'` will be interpreted as a `url_option` instead of a `html_option`

Comment: This is new code as you suggested = link_to('Reset message', {:action=>"reset"} ,{:confirm=>"Are you sure?"}).... and this is html <a href="/manage/reset" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Reset message</a> What is 'data-confirm'....stil not opened confirm message...Thanks.

Comment: `data-*` are [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) introduced in HTML5 which serve as storage areas for private data. `data-confirm` is used by rails to make the pop up appear when the link is clicked.

Comment: @Tini...have you included `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in the layout or page. Without that it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

In rails 7 with Turbo, I tried the solutions above and they didn't work for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046023/5783745) worked for me.

**Tip: copy the 4 methods below directly into a page of your app and test them!**

```
<%= link_to "GET turbo link", "/",
  data: {
    turbo_method: :get,
    turbo_confirm: "Sure?"
  }
%><br>

<%= link_to "POST turbo link", "/",
  data: {
    turbo_method: :post,
    turbo_confirm: "Sure?"
  }
%>

<%= button_to "Button", "/",
  data: { turbo_confirm: "Sure?" }
%>

<%= form_with url: "/",
  data: { turbo_confirm: "Sure?" } do |f| %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This info comes from this incredibly helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046023/5783745

Answer (score 1):

Somehow does not work those code only Safari browser So I was involved button...

```
<%= button_to('', delete_path(), method: "delete", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', disable_with: 'loading...' }) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The UJS library, which drove the confirm functionality you're describing, is [no longer enabled by default in Rails 7](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to-label-Deprecated-3A+Rails+UJS+Attributes). That functionality has been superseded by Turbo, but there's an [upgrade guide](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#upgrading-from-rails-ujs--turbolinks-to-turbo) to allow them to play nicely.

Instead, I would recommend implementing a modal-based confirmation, which Turbo makes incredibly easy. [GoRails has an easy tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/custom-hotwire-turbo-confirm-modals) on how to implement it.

One gotcha I missed: make sure to use `button_to` (not `link_to`), and don't nest the button within another form.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your javascript_include_tag and it should work fine:

```
<%= link_to("Reset message", :method => :reset, :class => 'action', :confirm => 'Are you sure?') %>
```

Comment: As pointed above, `:confirm` is now deprecated so you have to use either `"data-confirm" => ...` or `data: { confirm: ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

watch this railscasts video for better understanding.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

rails documentation for link_to helper.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to understand what Js package respond to this kind of alerts in rails application. So for this, jquery_ujs package is reponsible for showing the alerts in rails.

So you must have jquery & jquery_ujs in your application.js file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Now, we need to confirm, that application.js file is included in your required layout or not. By default layout file remains in application.html.erb in layout folder of views.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Next the link should have data-confirm & data-method attributes as

```
<a href="/message/1/reset" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">
```

In erb, this can be written as,

```
= link_to 'Reset', message_path(@message), data: {method: 'delete', confirm: 'Are you sure?'}
```

This should work if everything is aligned in same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7 with Turbo, the new approach is to use `data_turbo_confirm`:

```
= link_to 'Resource', resource_path(@resource), data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```