# jQuery causes Routing Error due to conflict with prototype.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I have built a sample app based on Michael Hartl's railstutorial v1, with Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.3. Everything was working fine till I added a slide-in menu called [pushy](http://christopheryee.ca/pushy/) which uses jquery v1.10.1.min and modernizr.custom.71422

After adding it, instead of a confirm pop-up box being displayed, I got the error `Route Error - No Route Matches "/dir/3"`.

I'm using the following code for the confirm pop-up

```
link_to "Remove", find_function(array[0]), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?", :title =>"Title"
```

I read on StackOverflow that it might be due to a conflict with prototype.js so I added

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

This step fixed the popup problem but the menu stopped working.

Please help me resolve this issue because I've spent almost 10 hours on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of my problem lay in the ancient version of Rails I was using i.e. v3.0.9

This ([How to add confirm message with link_to Ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668949/how-to-add-confirm-message-with-link-to-ruby-on-rails)) StackOverflow solution provided the initial direction of including

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

in the application.js files.

The jquery_ujs github page provided the actual answer of adding

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
```

to the gemfile and then running

```
bundle install
```

Finally, for Rails 3.0.X run

```
$ rails generate jquery:install
```

This command updated the public/javascripts folder. And peace was restored to the world.