# link_to confirm not working with controller/action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE - I just checked and NEITHER confirm is working.

I need to have a confirm on a link_to. I've tried a couple of variations on the data/confirm attribute but it is bypassing the confirm dialog.

My link is

```
 <%= link_to 'new bs line', 
   :controller => :bedsheet_lines, 
   :action => :create_new_bedsheet_line,  
   :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure that you want to export the Bedsheets?'} %> <br>
```

That does not work, <strike>but a regular link_to does:</strike> and neither does this

```
  <%= link_to "Export Data as a CSV file ", 
      slitter_bedsheet_export_path(format: "csv"), 
      :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure that you want to export the Bedsheets?'} %> <br>
```

If I do an inspect, the link that won't show the confirm looks like

```
  <a href="/bedsheet_lines/new_bedsheet_line?
   data%5Bconfirm%5D=Are+you+sure+that+you+want+to+export+the+Bedsheets%3F">
  new bs line</a> <br>
```

<strike>Whereas the link that does show a confirm looks like</strike>  Nor dies this work.

```
  <a data-confirm="Are you sure that you want to export the Bedsheets?" 
   href="/csv_export.csv">Export Data as a CSV file </a> <br>
```

My suspicion is that the problem is that confirm will not work when your link_to specifies and action and controller. If that is true, I should be able to find a way to work around that.  Now I'm not sure where my problem lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why the hash syntax matters but I use

```
<%= link_to 'text', path(param), data: { confirm: 'confirmation' } %>
```

Edit:

Specifying controller and action it would be:

```
<%= link_to 'text', { controller: 'bedsheet_lines', action: 'create_new_bedsheet_line' }, data: { confirm: 'confirmation' } %>
```

Comment: I was missing the brackets enclosing controller/action. Also, I found the a hint  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668949/how-to-add-confirm-message-with-link-to-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Apparently I had removed `//= require jquery_ujs` from application.js
 when I upgraded my Jquery libraries (Not sure exactly why I did that at that time). I put that line back in, made the changes you suggest,  precompiled, restarted the server and the confirms are now working