# Deprecation warning from Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am upgrading from rails 3.2.19 to rails 4.1.5, using rspec-rails 2.14.0.rc1 and capybara 2.4.1. All tests pass, and I only have one deprecation warning left:

```
[DEPRECATION] Capybara::Webkit::Driver#accept_js_confirms! is deprecated. Please use Capybara::Session#accept_confirm instead.
```

The line of code that is causing this is

```
page.driver.accept_js_confirms!
```

How do I change this line in order to eliminate the deprecation warning?

Comment: page.driver.browser.accept_confirm ?

Comment: Tried that myself as I'm having the same issue.   It doesn't work.   It does appear to recognize accept_modal(:confirm, options, &blk) but gives an argument error.   Still looking for the answer myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that the exception says:

> Please use Capybara::Session#accept_confirm instead.

You probably want:

```
page.accept_confirm
```

Note that `accept_confirm` is being run against the Capybara::Session instead of the driver.

This method expects a block that triggers the confirm alert to appear. For example:

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_link('that_opens_confirm')
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work, but you are right it's close to the right answer.   It's looking for a block.   I just don't understand how to pass it in.  Here's the raw code for it.

    # Execute the block, accepting a confirm.
    #
    # @macro modal_params
    #
    def accept_confirm(text_or_options=nil, options={}, &blk)
      if text_or_options.is_a? Hash
        options=text_or_options
      else
        options[:text]=text_or_options
      end
      
      driver.accept_modal(:confirm, options, &blk)
     end

Comment: Based on the [spec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/spec/session/accept_confirm_spec.rb), the block is supposed to be the actions that trigger the confirmation to appear.

Comment: That is helpful, but still can't quite place it.   I'm using cucumber and have a prompt that pops up in the previous step under page.driver.console_messages.first.

Switching to session by using page.accept_confirm should work but doesn't as I'm not passing something in.   I'm still a noob though :)

Comment: Actually, added the block like: page.accept_confirm do click_button('Ok) end but it doesn't work.   Says can't find the ok button but I am staring at it so it is there.

Comment: @Art, were you able to click the button before adding the `accept_confirm`? Is that OK button actually the button that triggers the confirm alert to *open*? The block is not supposed to be the button to close the alert.

Comment: In the browser, physically, there's an "OK" button.   I have tried click_link("OK") and click_button("OK") but both are not found.   And, it did (and does) work with the accept_js_confirms! method.   Also the method I put in earlier also works obviously.   Just would like to see this successful so I feel like I did :).

Comment: The button that triggers the alert is "Cancel my account" which pops up with the dialog box "Are you sure?" with an OK and Cancel option.   I open that earlier and evaluate the popu up iwth page.driver.console_messages.first in the previous step.   My guess is I should write these differently.   I see the xpath expect in the spec so may play with that.

Answer (score 6):

Justin Ko's answer is correct as to the usage of #accept_confirm - it's

```
page.accept_confirm do
  #code that will trigger the modal
end
```

or you can do

```
page.accept_confirm 'Are you sure?' do
  #code that will trigger the modal
end
```

which will verify that "Are you sure?" is the prompt displayed in the confirm box.

In your failing test do you happen to be dealing with another modal first?  capybara-webkit had a bug with multiple modals that was fixed a few days ago - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/commit/86e422f94422d39e537329d64d7bfe8f6360bd8b .  It's not in a relased version yet though.

Comment: Yes, I had two modals.  I separated them into two different scenarios and both tests passed.  So all is good apart from the bug you cite.

Answer (score 3):

I had 50/50 success with Justin Ko's answer.  The one that worked had code like this:

```
link_to "Reset", reset_pre_shot_description_mental_game_path(@mental_game), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "small_button round", id: "reset_pre-shot"
```

and this test:

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_link "Reset"
end
```

The test that fails (but has code that works in the browser) has code

```
link_to 'Delete', micropost, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete
```

and test

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_link "Delete"
end
```

The failure message was

```
Failure/Error: page.accept_confirm do
Capybara::ModalNotFound:
  Timed out waiting for modal dialog
```

I tried moving the `method: :delete` into the `:data` hash, but this did not help.

It turns out that the deprecation warning actually found two bugs in the code, as I was using the rails 3 syntax for confirm i.e. not using the `:data` hash, so my code was broken but the `page.driver.accept_js_confirms!` test was not picking it up. So this has been worthwhile tracking down.

Comment: As mentioned in response to user2209090's identification of a bug, there were two modals in the test, when I separated each into a different scenario, the 'Delete" test worked.  So I now put Justin Ko's answer at 100% with the proviso in regard to the bug in user229090's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced page.driver.accept_js_confirms! with:

page.execute_script('window.confirm = function() { return true }')

And the test passed.

This was from the documentation here:  http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#evaluate_script-instance_method

And help from the internets.   Now, that doesn't still tell us how to use accept_confirm so I'm still looking for that answer.

The actual code looks like this:

```
# Execute the block, accepting a confirm.
#
# @macro modal_params
#
def accept_confirm(text_or_options=nil, options={}, &blk)
  if text_or_options.is_a? Hash
    options=text_or_options
  else
    options[:text]=text_or_options
  end

  driver.accept_modal(:confirm, options, &blk)
 end
```

Honestly, I think it's just page.accept_confirm with SOMETHING else, but I can't figure out what or passing in that block.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect for me:

```
page.execute_script('window.confirm = function() { return true }')
```