# Test Alert Dialog Text Using Capybara Webkit 1.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm looking to test the text in an alert dialog using Capybara Webkit. I'm aware of the `accept_js_confirms` and `reject_js_confirms` methods, but I'm looking to evaluate the contents of the dialog prior to performing an action. In Selenium for example, the following works:

`alert = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
 expect(alert.text).to eq t('report_periods.edit.delete_confirmation')
 alert.accept`

I'm currently using `expect(page.driver.confirm_messages).to include t('report_periods.edit.delete_confirmation')` to test the text of the same dialog, however, after updating our capybara-webkit gem our tests output a deprecation warning: `[DEPRECATION] Capybara::Webkit::Driver#confirm_messages is deprecated. Please use Capybara::Session#accept_confirm or Capybara::Session#dismiss_confirm instead.` Using either of those methods from the warning will not test the contents of the dialog though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

accept_confirm and dismiss_confirm will only accept or dismiss the modal.

If you want to compare the text the you can take the return value of accept_confirm in a variable and then later you can compare it.

```
message = accept_prompt(with: 'Linus Torvalds') do
  click_link('Show Prompt About Linux')
end
expect(message).to eq('Who is the chief architect of Linux?')
```

Look at Modals here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh! I discovered this on my own as well using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26348968/810794