# How to click on one of links with the same text using Capybara in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am testing the user management feature of my app on Rails 5 by cucumber and capybara. In the Users page, all users are listed and there is a "delete" link for each user.
I have no idea about clicking the 4th user's delete in this page.

```
first(:link, "delete").click
```

I know this line above can select the first "delete", but what about those are not the first or the last?

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                            data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

This is how this link is implemented by erb.

Actually there is another question. As the code above, there is a JavaScript confirm popup after I click "delete". How to click that "OK" button? [How do I confirm a javascript popup with Capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930927/how-do-i-confirm-a-javascript-popup-with-capybara) Answers here do not work.

Comment: You need to scope your find to the correct section of the page -- How do you know it's the 4th user you want to click delete on? Use that info to scope to the correct place - Add the surrounding HTML to you question for more help on that (actual HTML not the erb template).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `all` to find multiple matching elements and then index into them

```
all(:link, 'delete')[3].click # 0 based index so 3 is the fourth element
```

however depending on what exactly you're testing that can lead to fragile tests. If your requirement is to delete the user named "Joe Smith" and you had elements like

```
<div class="user">Bob Jones<a href=...>delete</a></div>
<div class="user">Joe Smith<a href=...>delete</a></div>
...
```

then you'd be better off scoping your click to the correct section of the page by doing something along the lines of

```
find('div.user', text: 'Joe Smith').click_link('delete')
```

Combining that with a system confirm would be

```
accept_confirm do
  find('div.user', text: 'Joe Smith').click_link('delete')
end
```

Note: `accept_confirm` only applies to system confirms (those opened by JS `Window.confirm`). If you have confirm "modals" from a JS widget library then you need to interact with them just like any other page content.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar approach but a bit different... ideally you would have posted a little more info on your spec and view but maybe this will help you.

Your links probably have a wrapper tag. If they don't add one. If they do add a unique id to each wrapper:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
  <div id="user_<%= user.id %>">
    <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  </div>
  <div id="user_<%= user.id %>">
    <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  </div>
  <div id="user_<%= user.id %>">
    <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Depending on how your building your spec data in your capybara tests you can do this:

```
it "clicks on a user", :js do
  let(:user4) { create(:user) }

  within("user_#{user4.id}") do
    accept_confirm { click_link("delete") }
  end
end
```

Or something like this:

```
it "clicks on a user", :js do
  let(:users) { create_list(:user, 4) }

  within("user_4") do
    accept_confirm { click_link("delete") }
  end
end
```

As Thomas mentioned you need to enable the `javascript_driver` for your test by adding the `:js` which will use `selenium` by default or other if you've configured it to.