# javascript alert .press 'Ok' with capybara and cucumber test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

i am using caoybara , selenium and cucumber . i wana click an alert box with 'ok' button. help me out this code is not clicking the button:

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
page.click("Ok")
```

Comment: See my answer here for the newer way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26472467/2170577

Answer (score 12):

Get a reference to the alert using the following:

```
alert = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
```

And then

```
alert.accept
```

To hit 'Ok'

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `switch_to' for  #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:0x00000006aaf888>

Answer (score 0):

Jon's didn't work for me probably because I'm using a newer version of capybara (2.1.0)

This worked for me:

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
```